# Using Numpy to find Mean,Median,Mode or Range of inputted set of numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I am creating a program to find Mean,Median,Mode, or Range. When I run this it works fine until it gets to the part of calculating the answer. It gives me a "cannot preform reduce with flexible type" error. I have searched this error but could not find what I needed to fix. This is my first time using numpy so any help would be great.

```
import sys
import numpy as np

welcomeString = input("Welcome to MMMR Calculator\nWhat would you like to calculate(Mean,Median,Mode,Range):")

if welcomeString.lower() == "mean":
   meanNumbers = input("What numbers would you like to use?:")
   print (np.average(meanNumbers))
   stop = input()

if welcomeString.lower() == "median":
    medianNumbers = input("What numbers would like to use?:")
    print (np.median(medianNumbers))
    stop = input()

if welcomeString.lower() == "mode":
    modeNumbers = input("What numbers would you like to use?:")
    print (np.mode(modeNumbers))
    stop = input()

if welcomeString.lower() == "range":
    rangeNumbers = input("What numbers would you like to use?:")
    print (np.arange(rangeNumbers))
    stop = input()
```

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616303/finding-sum-of-a-column-in-a-list-getting-typeerror-cannot-perform-reduce-with

Comment: When I do that, and find the mean of 1,2,3,4, it prints out function mean at 0x02330858. What does that mean?

Comment: IF you catch the answer to the first question in a variable you can avoid writing the second question four times. Also, what is the last input() in the four options about?

Comment: What do you mean by catch the answer. I put the last input() there to stop the program so I could see the output before the window closed.

Comment: Does `np.arange` really calculate range?! I though it was supposed to generate numbers within a range ?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing a string to the functions which is not allowed.

```
>>> meanNumbers = input("What numbers would you like to use?:")
What numbers would you like to use?:1 2 3 4 5 6
>>> np.average(meanNumbers)
    #...
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

You need to make an array or a list out of them.

```
>>> np.average(list(map(float, meanNumbers.split())))
3.5
```

IF you're seperating the elements by commas, split on the commas.

```
>>> np.average(list(map(float, meanNumbers.split(','))))
    3.5
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more information on map and float because when I tried what you posted I got "Unsupported operand type error".

Comment: Can you post the full traceback please?

Comment: You just post whatever you get when you execute that line of code.

Comment: Do you mean the File "C:\Progr" lines or ret = ret / float(rcount)

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions|Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.0\visualstudio_py_util" line 70, in exec_file exec(code_obj, global_variables)

Comment: File "C:\Users\username\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MMMRCalculator\MMMRCalculator\MMMRCalculator.py", line 8 in (module) Print(np.average(map(float(),meanNumbers.split())))

Comment: Do you need the rest?

Comment: Hi! You seem to have a `P` in your `Print` which should be print, also, paste the last line of my answer as it is in your code, you are calling `float` using `float()` which is not possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not even realize what I did.

Comment: @Hartbypass : I installed Numpy for Python 3.3 and fixed your error in the above lines. `map` returns a map object which is not supported by numpy, converting it to a list solved the problem. See the fixed code above.

Answer (score 6):

This is not an answer (see @Sukrit Kalra's response for that), but I see an opportunity to demonstrate how to write cleaner code that I cannot pass up.  You have a large amount of code duplication that will result in difficult to maintain code in the future.  Try this instead:

```
import sys
import numpy as np

welcomeString = input("Welcome to MMMR Calculator\nWhat would you like to calculate(Mean,Median,Mode,Range):")
welcomeString = welcomeString.lower() # Lower once and for all

# All averages need to do this
numbers = input("What numbers would you like to use?:")
numbers = list(map(float, numbers.split(','))) # As per Sukrit Kalra's answer

# Use a map to get the function you need
average_function = { "mean": np.average,
                     "median": np.median,
                     "mode": np.mode,
                     "range": np.arange,
                   } 

# Print the result of the function by passing in the
# pre-formatted numbers from input
try:
    print (average_function[welcomeString](numbers))
except KeyError:
    sys.exit("You entered an invalid average type!")

input() # Remove when you are done with development
```

Comment: Thanks this will definitely help in the future. As to the stop = input(), it lets me see the output before the code window closes. Is that bad?

Comment: For development I suppose it is OK, but I certainly wouldn't keep it if you plan to share it with anyone.  It wouldn't be needed if run from the command line.

Comment: Hey, when you edited the code, I tried to run it and got "unsupported operand type :/ for 'map' and 'float'. What could be causing this?

Comment: You need to be specific on what input you're giving and what your code is. Please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I used his solution in my code.  Based on the comments for his solution, it seemed that you had gotten it to work.  I agree with Sukrit, you need to provide us with an example of what you will be typing when the program prompts you with "What numbers would you like to use?:"

Comment: Not only that, the OP seems to have mistyped what I had given as the answer, he should never get an unsupported type / for map and float, unless he's doing something completely different.

Comment: Did you accidentally write `map/float` instead of `map(float`?

Comment: @SethMMorton : The problem seems to be Numpy which cannot take map objects yet, I fixed the code. You can reflect the appropriate changes in your code too. :)